# Get Jenkins pipeline WORKSPACE environment variable in Windows format

Tags: windows, jenkins

I am trying to pass through the name of the workspace to a Windows batch file so that it can be used to build filenames etc., something like this.

```
stage('Execute Batch') {
    steps {
        script {
            bat label: '', script: "batchfile.bat ${env.WORKSPACE}\\"
        }
    }
}
```

The problem I have is that the path contains forward slashes instead of backslashes, e.g. `C:/Jenkins/Workspace/my-pipline` instead of `C:\Jenkins\Workspace\my-profile`.

I cannot find anything in the documentation (or searching on the web) that will allow me to use the Windows format of the workspace environment variable.

Comment: Seems like I am not alone in experiencing this issue.
https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-5084